# Question about derivative and duality product in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces

I have a $C^1$ function $J: X\to \mathbb{R}$ where X is a Banach space
Why is this identity true ?
$$
J(u)-J(v)=\langle J'(t u +(1-t)v), u-v\rangle ,t\in (0,1), u,v\in X.
$$

Comment: Not every Banach space has an inner product, only Hilbert spaces. Is $X$ an Hilbert space?

Comment: That is somehow like $\varphi\in X^{\ast}$, $\varphi(x)$ is written as $\left<\varphi,x\right>$. The derivative here should be assumed as the Frechet version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which derivative is defined there, but if it were the Frechet one, then the following is true, look at *Real and Functional Analysis*, Serge Lang.

\begin{align*}
J(u)-J(v)&=J(v+(u-v))-J(v)\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}J'(v+t(u-v))(u-v)dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}J'(tu+(1-t)v)dt\cdot(u-v)\\
&=\left<\int_{0}^{1}J'(tu+(1-t)v)dt,u-v\right>.
\end{align*}

Comment: The integral stay in the product ?

Comment: Interestingly, it can be swiped, that is, it can be exterior one, you may look at the proof of Serge Lang book.

Comment: do you have the page please ?

Comment: It is Page 341.

Comment: But I wonder if you define derivative in the other sense, the expression may go through, let me do some research.

Answer (score 0):

Let us define $\varphi : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ via
$$\varphi(t) = J( u + t \, (v - u) ).$$

If $J$ is Gateaux-differentiable, then $\varphi$ is differentiable and you can apply the ordinary mean value theorem.

Comment: $f$ ??? @gerw i don't understand

Comment: I have replaced $f$ by $J$...

Comment: but the mean value theorem gives the existence of c such that... here there is no c

Comment: The mean value theorem gives the existence of $t \in (0,1)$ such that the equation in your question holds.

Comment: this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.